# Pass data from Spring Boot app into javascript function

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, thymeleaf, google-maps-markers

I am trying to pass latitude and longitude data from a MySQL database through my Spring Boot application into a javascript function. I was able to use Thymeleaf to display a table on the webpage with the data, so I know the service and controller classes are set up correctly.

Below shows how my table is populated:

```
<table style="word-wrap:break-word;white-space:normal;" class="table table-bordered">
    <thead class="table-dark">
        <tr>
            <th>Latitude</th>
            <th>Longitude</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <th:block th:each="point : ${listPoints}">
            <tr>
                <td>[[${point.LAT}]]</td>
                <td>[[${point.LNG}]]</td>
            </tr>
        </th:block>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I also hard coded the params of my javascript function which works. Below is the js function:

```
addMarker({lat:50.772775,lng:3.889969});

function addMarker(coords) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: coords,
        map:map
    })
}
```

I need a way to loop through my lat and lng's to add a marker for each. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have a class `Point`:

```
public class Point {
   double lat;
   double lng
   // getters omitted
}
```

Further your servlet/controller passes a list of points as attribute `listPoints` to the Thymeleaf page, so that it shows in your table:

```
    <tbody>
        <th:block th:each="point : ${listPoints}">
            <tr>
                <td>[[${point.lat}]]</td>
                <td>[[${point.lng}]]</td>
            </tr>
        </th:block>
    </tbody>
```

In your JavaScript (wherever this lays) you have to call the `addMarker` function for each of all those coordinates.
For example:

```
addMarker({lat:50.772775,lng:3.889969});
```

for the first point and so on.

You could pass the points inside a [javascript-inlining](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#javascript-inlining) block to your Thymeleaf page:

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
    var points = /*[[${listPoints}]]*/ null;
    console.log(points);  // just a debug print to verify all points received
    points.forEach(p => addMarker(p));
</script>
```

Now you have to make sure that this script with populated points is loaded in the correct order (when `addMarker` function is ready to add markers on the map). You can also wrap this inside a function that is invoked `onload`.

See also:

- [Setting up a JavaScript variable in Thymeleaf](https://attacomsian.com/blog/thymeleaf-set-javascript-variable)
- [What html tags support the onload/onerror javascript event attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679704/what-html-tags-support-the-onload-onerror-javascript-event-attributes)
- [GoogleMap API with Java/Springboot and Thymeleaf receiving the coordenates but not creating the map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63066288/googlemap-api-with-java-springboot-and-thymeleaf-receiving-the-coordenates-but-n)